# ASP.Net Website is creating a new session on each load

Tags: asp.net, session, iis, session-cookies

I've recently moved an ASP.Net (3.5) application to a new server, and it has developed an odd issue that I'm having problems troubleshooting.

On each and every page load no matter what browser I'm using (IE, FF, Chrome) ASP.Net/IIS issues me a new Session on each page load, forgetting the previous session it called.

I have a simple page for testing this out as follows:

```
<asp:Button ID="Button1" Visible="true" runat="server" Text="Button" />

    <%= HttpContext.Current.Session("Test")%>
    <br /><br />
    <%= Session("GlobalTest") %> 
    <a href="Test.aspx">Reload the page</a>
```

In the Code Behind I have this for the Button:

```
    HttpContext.Current.Session("Test") = DateTime.Now.ToLongTimeString
```

In Global.asax

```
    Sub Session_Start(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)
        ' Code that runs when a new session is started
        Session("GlobalTest") = "Session Created on : " + DateTime.Now.ToLongTimeString()
    End Sub
```

When you push the button, it initially displays the Session value just fine. Go to reload the page, either via- the link, or just loading fresh and the information (except for the Global that now updates to a new time) goes away.

In web.config, the session is setup thus:

```
<sessionState mode="InProc" timeout="15" useHostingIdentity="false" cookieless="false" />
```

Has anyone experienced similar to this?

Comment: The session is depend from the `cookies`. How do you have setup the `httpCookies` on the web.config ?

Comment: I do not currently have an httpCookies in web.config.

Comment: Then add one, and make sure you setup the domain.

Comment: Tried that, but the whole site collapsed with error 500.19:

"The requested page cannot be accessed because the related configuration data for the page is invalid."

Answer (score 1):

Okay, I figured it out. Thanks for all the suggestions.

Turns out what was going on was a lesser known tag to me,  in the web config and I hadn't setup SSL Certs for that site yet. Remove that and works like a charm. Not slated to do that til next week.

This does create awkward behavior... It won't set a cookie for anyone ever, but you can use Session per normal and it will work properly for the first load when it then resets the cookie session (and you aren't over SSL).

Thanks again everyone.

Answer (score 0):

put session in !IsPostBack rule and try again

Comment: Created this on Page_Load:

`If Not IsPostBack Then
            Session("Postback_test") = "Post Back Test : " + DateTime.Now.ToLongTimeString()

        End If`
And the value set on first load does not display at all (does not exist) after post back, the session value in its entirety just goes away. it appears.

Comment: can you try to put your session values in viewstate and see if its losing their too.

Answer (score 0):

Be sure you are not writing to bin directory, beause that will reset Application and Session variables each time it is written to.

Comment: There isn't actually a bin folder in this web site (It's a web site over web application). I even took the Test.aspx page that was in this site to a separate folder with the web.config and a global.asmx file and created a new application off of it, and the same thing is happening there as well in this smaller section of the web site... It keeps forgetting session variables in proc on each load.